# Wait to Continue - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I need any solution to solve this problem. I need to read a property that will receive the data from an http request. So, I need to test this property only when the transaction completes.

```
  checkAuthorization(path: string): boolean{
    const usuarioLogado: UsrStoraged = this.storage.getUsuarioLogado();
    let usuario: Usuario
    this.usuarioService.findByLogin(usuarioLogado.login).subscribe(
        data => {
            usuario = data
        }

    )

    if (usuario.perfil.springSecurity == 'ROLE_ADMIN'){
        return true;
    } else {
        const message: Message = {message: 'Usuário sem permissão', type: TipoMensagem.ERROR}
        this.message.notify(message)
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this for use with a `RouteGuard`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the function to return an observable instead, and use `map` to convert the data to your boolean result.

```
checkAuthorization(path: string): Observable<boolean>{
    const usuarioLogado: UsrStoraged = this.storage.getUsuarioLogado();
    return this.usuarioService.findByLogin(usuarioLogado.login).pipe(map(
        data => {
            const usuario = data

            if (usuario.perfil.springSecurity == 'ROLE_ADMIN'){
                return true;
            } else {
                const message: Message = {message: 'Usuário sem permissão', type: TipoMensagem.ERROR}
                this.message.notify(message)
                return false;
            }
        }
    ))
}
```

You'll also need to add imports if you don't already have them:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs"
import {map} from "rxjs/operators"
```

---

Then, you'll have to modify any code that calls this function to subscribe to the result.  E.g. instead of

```
if (checkAuthorization("foo")) {
    // do stuff
} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

You would use

```
checkAuthorization("foo").subscribe(isAuthorized => {
    if (isAuthorized) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

`data => {` will be called if you receive it, so you can just move your code inside like this:

```
checkAuthorization(path: string): boolean{
    const usuarioLogado: UsrStoraged = this.storage.getUsuarioLogado();
    let usuario: Usuario
    this.usuarioService.findByLogin(usuarioLogado.login).subscribe(
        data => {
            usuario = data
            if (usuario.perfil.springSecurity == 'ROLE_ADMIN'){
                return true;
            } else {
                const message: Message = {message: 'Usuário sem permissão', type: TipoMensagem.ERROR}
                this.message.notify(message)
                return false;

            }
        } 
    );
}
```

**Hint:** To handle the error case add `error => {}` analog to `data` below.

Comment: Returning from inside the `subscribe` is not the same as returning from `checkAuthorization`